# Starting in xx days/hours and xx minutes with PHP

Tags: php

I found lots of solutions for showing a timestamp to xx days, xx hours and minutes **ago** but not really anything in future looking.

I would like to output:

```
Starting in 2 days, 5 hours and 22 minutes
```

From this unix timestamp: 1331596800

```
    $timestamp = new DateTime();
    $timestamp->setTimestamp(1331596800);
    $diff = $timestamp->diff(new DateTime());

    return $diff->format('%h hours, %i minutes');
```

Is something clean and easy I found, but it does not show me the correct hours / minutes.

How can i do this?

Comment: You formatted your date wrong. See the [built-in `date` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for mroe info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a piece of code from one of my applications:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); // set the TimeZone. I am from India.

$today_date = new DateTime('now');  // now
$final_date = new DateTime('2012-03-22 09:00'); // a date in the future
$interval = $today_date->diff($final_date); // find the difference

$time_left = $interval->format('%D days, %H hours, %I minutes, %S seconds'); // display it
```

This is just an example. I hope you'll be able to understand it from the comments.

Comment: DateTime is just <3 for date formatting and calcs, but be careful what functions you use and on what version of php.

Comment: @danp: Yeah, the above one needs PHP 5.3 for working. Sorry ,but I didn't got this part: `.. is just <3 ..`, that you mentioned above. Did you mean, it is not accurate ? Or did you mean `apt for date formatting` ?

Comment: ah, it was a heart, to show that I love this feature :) or... &#x2665; if that's your thing too (like in the advert!)

Comment: I am slow at picking up things :D
Thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Do you know how i can hide %D days if there is 0 days left?

Comment: I think, you could assign values (days, hours, minutes, seconds) to separate variables - for this, call the format() passing `%d`, `%h`, etc. Then check whether each is greater than 0. If so, append it to a new variable. And finally output it.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP countdown timer have a look on SO[SO: PHP Countdown Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025772/php-countdown-timer-problem)
In case if you are interested to use jQuery here are some good ones with good documentations.
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery/

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

http://www.ricocheting.com/code/javascript/html-generator/countdown-timer

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$timestamp = 1331596800 - time();
$string = "Starting in ".date('d', $timestamp)." days, ".date('h', $timestamp)." hours and ".date('m', $timestamp)." minutes";
echo $string;`